# python conda interpreter ERROR: double free or corruption (out)

Tags: python, python-3.x, conda, miniconda

Use:

```
conda==25.1.2
python==3.10.13
fastapi== 0.110.0
uvicorn==0.28.0
torchvision==0.17.1
torchaudio==2.2.1
```

---

`run.sh` file (it worked before error):

```bash
### venv
conda activate ./venv


./venv/bin/uvicorn 'app.main:main' --host="0.0.0.0" --port=8000 --ssl-keyfile=certs/key.pem --ssl-certfile=certs/cert.pem --reload
```

I was working before...
the reason maybe My Ubuntu 22.04.3 system did some updates

I don't know what's the reason of this error.. I did some changes on my code, But all changes reset for this issue... Still this error if want to run:

#### ERROR

```
$ sh ./run.sh
...
2024-03-15 11:27:43,279 - INFO - app.main:24 - Starting main app
INFO:     Started server process [8668]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
double free or corruption (out)

venv23/lib/python3.10/multiprocessing/resource_tracker.py:224: UserWarning: resource_tracker: There appear to be 1 leaked semaphore objects to clean up at shutdown
  warnings.warn('resource_tracker: There appear to be %d '
`
```

Comment: This needs clearer explanation of what environment(s) these commands are run in. Note that `conda` should never be installed outside **base**. `conda update --all` is counterproductive to wanting code to stably work, and doesn't make sense to follow up with install specific versions of packages. Consider defining your environment with YAML and avoid mutating it.

Comment: re-create conda env and install packages.
Worked as needed!